# How do I set up a ROS mirror?

Tags: ros, installation, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At my university, we have several computers that have ROS installed on them.  If I have access to a server, how do I set up a mirror of the ROS Ubuntu repository to speed up installing ROS packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9163/how-do-i-set-up-a-ros-mirror?/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-22**:
A link from the ubuntu mirrors page seems like a good idea

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-22**:
Any problems with me adding this to the wiki entry for mirrors?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-22**:
I accepted it for you

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-22**:
Can i get an admin to allow normal users to accept their own answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To do this, begin by installing apt-mirror on your Ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-mirror
```

Then edit the mirror.list (/etc/apt/mirror.list) file so that the ROS repositories will be mirrored, here is an example for both x86 and amd64 systems.

```
############# config ##################                                                                                                                                                                              
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

#deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jaunty main
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu karmic main
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu maverick main

#deb-i386 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jaunty main
deb-i386 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu karmic main                                                                                                                                                              
deb-i386 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main
deb-i386 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu maverick main
```

Once apt-mirror is set up, you can mirror the repository by running the command:

```
sudo su - apt-mirror -c apt-mirror
```

This may take a while the first time that you run it.  This will download a copy of the ROS repository to /var/spool/apt-mirror by default.

You can now set up Apache to point to the mirror so that it is accessible through http.

As an example, here is my Apache configuration (/etc/apache2/sites-available/mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    ServerName mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com
    ServerAlias www.mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com
    ServerAdmin XXXXXXX@ieee.org
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com"

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com/error_log

     <Directory "/var/www/mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com">
            Options +Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>


    <IfModule log_config_module>
            TransferLog /var/log/apache2/mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com/access_log
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you may enable the site and create a symlink to the apt-mirror directory:

```
sudo a2ensite mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com
sudo ln -s /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/code.ros.org /var/www/mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com/archive-ros
```

Your mirror will be available at http://mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com/archive-ros/

You can add it to your local apt repository using the following command:

```
sudo sh -c '. /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://mirror.<+YOURDOMAIN+>.com/archive-ros/packages/ros/ubuntu $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

And then follow the rest of the ROS install guide.

It also helps to set up a cron task to keep the repository synced, do this by uncommenting the line in /etc/cron.d/apt-mirror

```
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
# Regular cron jobs for the apt-mirror package
#
0 4 * * *   apt-mirror  /usr/bin/apt-mirror > /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/cron.log
```

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2011-02-22**:
You can also get the repository over [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) from some locations (e.g., umoss.org). Just remember to use the --delay-updates and --delete-delay parameters so that your mirror never enters an inconsistent state. (Any chance of getting an rsync server at WG?)

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-22**:
I would have included our mirror, but I'm not sure how our university's IT department feels about that.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-22**:
Unless the Ubuntu package automatically enables cron, you may also have to add a cronjob entry in order for apt-mirror to run regularly. I had to do so on my Funtoo box that is the CWRU ROS mirror.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-22**:
can you change the instructions to use packages.ros.org?  We are migrating to that being our primary server due to load issues.  We actually update packages.ros.org first, then backsync to code.ros.org.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-04-22**:
There are now official mirroring instructions at: http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors